# Python decomposing a dict

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

I have a dict like

```
start = 50
end = 84
data = {
    '50-52': 781445.0, 
    '52-84': 56554260.0, 
    '50-73': 31204670.0, 
    '73-84': 39169560.0,
    '73-75' : 23123123.0,
    '75-84' : 2312322.0
}
```

**What I want to achieve?**

I want to traverse all possible paths from start to end, eg: for the above example

```
>  x = data['50-52'] + data['52-84'] = 781445.0 + 56554260.0
>  y = data['50-73'] + data['73-84'] = 31204670.0 + 39169560.0
>  z = data['50-73'] + data['73-75'] + data['75-84'] = 31204670.0 + 23123123.0 + 2312322.0
```

and I would like to get a `list` of all possible paths from start to end that is `[x, y, z]`

I have sort of hit a dead end with the different ways I have been trying to approach this. I have tried to create new dict and update it with each iteration but the code seems to get very complex, any ideas on what approach I can take?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of information is best represented using graphs:

```
import networkx as nx


data = {
    '50-52': 781445.0, 
    '52-84': 56554260.0, 
    '50-73': 31204670.0, 
    '73-84': 39169560.0,
    '73-75' : 23123123.0,
    '75-84' : 2312322.0
}

G = nx.DiGraph()
for key, weight in data.items():
    src_str, dest_str = key.split('-')
    src_idx, dest_idx = int(src_str), int(dest_str)
    G.add_edge(src_idx, dest_idx, weight=weight)

start = 50
end = 84

all_paths = list(nx.all_simple_paths(G, 
                                    source=start, 
                                    target=end))
distances = [sum(G.get_edge_data(s,d)['weight'] for s,d in zip(p,p[1:])) 
             for p in all_paths]


results = {tuple(p):d for p,d in zip(all_paths,distances)}


print(results)
```

The results are:

```
{
(50, 52, 84): 57335705.0, 
(50, 73, 84): 70374230.0, 
(50, 73, 75, 84): 56640115.0
}
```

Networkx can be a bit tricky, but it's definitely worth learning about!

Answer (score 1):

You could also brute force it with `combinations`.
I'm not sure how large your `dict` is but if you only need to compute it once or twice, here's a solution.

```
from itertools import combinations

def get_paths(start, end, all_paths):
    paths = []

    # this will produce a list of tuples of all the coordinates
    # convert to ints for sorting purposes
    cooards = [(int(i.split('-')[0]), int(i.split('-')[1])) for i in all_paths]

    # this produces a list of all possible combinations
    # of those coordinates
    # basically a list of all possible lengths
    # of all possible combinations for each length
    combs = [x for l in range(1, len(cooards) + 1) for x in combinations(cooards, l)]

    for path in combs:
        # sort the path so we can traverse it in order to see if 
        # the end element matches the start of the next element
        full_path = sorted(path)

        path_start = full_path[0][0]
        path_end = full_path[-1][1]

        # invlidate anything without a proper start and end point
        if start == path_start and end == path_end:
            # paths with a length of 1 immediately qualify
            if len(full_path) == 1:
                paths.append(['-'.join(str(j) for j in i) for i in path])
            else:
                # if we get through our entire path without breaking we qualify
                for i, cooard in enumerate(full_path[:-1]):
                    if cooard[1] != full_path[i + 1][0]:
                        break
                else:
                    # convert back to strings so we can use the keys
                    paths.append(['-'.join(str(j) for j in i) for i in path])

    return paths


start = 50
end = 84
data = {
    '50-52': 781445.0, 
    '52-84': 56554260.0, 
    '50-73': 31204670.0, 
    '73-84': 39169560.0,
    '73-75' : 23123123.0,
    '75-84' : 2312322.0
}

print(get_paths(start, end, data))
```

From here it would be easy to get the sum of the returned keys.